# PyAutoGUI Python 3.5 Shell

Tags: pyautogui

I installed Pyautogui correctly and a I can import it from Python 3.5 but not from a script in IDLE Python 3.5.2

On the Shell the module pyautogui could not be found

Comment: Did you try **uninstalling** and then **installing** it again?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same version of Python both times? (Compare the text when they first start to see the Python version number.) Did you install Python by using pip?

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer why an error is coming, but I may be able to solve your issue
Run this code on your Shell:

```
from subprocess import *
from sys import *

call([executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "pyautogui"])
```

Hope it helps :|